# Using CommonJ WorkManagerTaskExecutor Spring 3 for multithreading

Tags: java

Hello everyone I am new to the forum and I just had a question about working with Spring's commonj WorkManagerTaskExecutor.  I have been on a bunch of forums looking for better information on the subject but I haven't seen anything detailed on the subject.  So here is my situation.

My application uses multiple threads which were being handled by ThreadPoolTaskExecutor which a friend told me he thought would not be the correct choice since we are using websphere 7.0 application server.  I had everything working correctly and with some minor tweaking was able to replace the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with a WorkManagerTaskExecutor.  When I run the application the threads fire off via the default work manager on the websphere server.  The problem that seems to be happening though is that even though I am using the workManagerTaskExecutor.waitForAll(collection,timeout); It never actually waits for the threads to complete.  I know that it is working that is the threads are executing their respective methods because if you issue a lengthy for loop after all of this the data is there where as if you do not the data is not there.  I was wondering the following two things.

1. Is the WorkManagerTaskExecutor the way to go?  Or would using a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor be sufficient for handling multiple threads on a enterprise web application?
2. If the WorkManagerTaskExecutor is the way to go?  Any ideas as to why the waitForAll method is completing as if the methods are done?  When clearly they are not?  After the page loads I can see in the logging that the methods are still running and eventually completeing.

Any help would be much appreciated.  If I left anything out I will gladly try and give more information about the issue as I truly appreciate any help that might be given.

Thanks in Advance,

Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement your concurrent class by extending the [java.util.concurrent.Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface built into JavaSE, and then using the [Spring IoC container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html), you can inject in an implementation class of [WorkManagerTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/commonj/WorkManagerTaskExecutor.html) when running under Websphere.

This will give you flexibility if you ever want to run on another Java app server, and even works if you run outside a container directly on the JVM, since you could inject in a [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/backportconcurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) and not have to change any code.

You should avoid coding against the CommonJ WorkManager API (JSR 237) directly, such as using the `waitForAll` method, since it only works on IBM Websphere and Oracle WebLogic.

Comment: Drew,  Does this mean that If I need code to ensure the thread completes before continuing on in my code that this would all be coded within the executor?  The WorkManagerTaskExecutor would just be the platform for the executor?

Comment: Basically what I am doing is modifying existing code from a huge system.  The problem is that peeling apart the system at this point is pretty much impossible so I am forced to do this in effort to gain performance.  Before we had about 20 data sources being fetched one at a time which was dreadfully slow.  By using the ThreadPooltaskExecutor I was able to fetch all 20 at the same time which increases the speed by a ton.

Comment: The only problem is that because of the code I have to ensure that the method that executes this task does not continue until all of the threads have completed. So I guess if I were to extend using the executor and the inject an implementation of the workManagerTaskExecutor how can I ensure the method does not continue without using something like waitForAll?

Comment: Yes, except that this code would not be _within_ your custom Executor implementation.  The `waitForAny` will go away, and the code you need to wait on will be wrapped in a `Callable` and you'll need a `Future` to check that it is done.

Comment: The `Executor` interface accepts only Runnable instances, so you may need to use `org.springframework.core.taskInterface.AsyncTaskExecutor`, but the implementation would still be the same (like WorkManagerTaskExecutor for Websphere).

Comment: Thanks so much this was very informative I will check this out in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

The final winning combination to this problem for me ended up being:

```
List<Callable<?>> callables = new ArrayList<Callable<?>>();
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
    for (int i = 0; i<callers.length;i++){
        callables.add(new MainTaskExecutor(this,entity,callers[i]));

    }
    for (Callable c:callables){
        futures.add(workTaskExecutor.submit(c));
    }
    for (Future<?> f:futures){
        do{}while(!f.isDone());
    }
```

Comment: isn't it put the code in continues loop known as pooling if we have long running threads